# Router - some devices get internet other dns errors

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, wireless-router

This is a really strange situation. We have a pretty recent Linksys router and like 30% of devices can connect to it and get internet. The other 70% can still connect to the router but internet doesn't work and they keep getting dns not found errors.

It seems completely random(but always the same devices work). It's not OS based issue, as we tried connecting from linux,iOS,android... It's also not limited number of slots as we tried turning wifi off on working devices and restarting router and first connecting from ones that didn't work before. But nothing.

Any ideas?

Edit: Thanks to grawity suggestion, here is `dig` output from the device where the internet doesn't work:

```
dig linux.org

; <<>> DiG 9.14.4 <<>> linux.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 64246
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;linux.org.         IN  A

;; Query time: 5 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.42.1#53(192.168.42.1)
;; WHEN: sáb sep 14 10:33:18 -05 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 27
```

It throws this instantly.

Comment: Do all those devices use exactly the same DNS servers? Is it just one server (the router) or multiple? Can you show the actual errors, ideally by doing lookups with `dig` on Linux?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I updated the question with the output from dig command.

Comment: As @grawity suggest I would also check the dns server on the working devices.  Make sure they are all connecting to the same dns server and not a secondary or backup.